# Проблема с вводом нового значения переменной

Tags: java, алгоритм

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при создании крестиков-ноликов. В моей версии нолик может заменить крестик, даже если клетка уже занята. Поэтому решил добавить записывание ходов и условие (если клетка занята, то введите другую). Но не могу придумать, как при таком условии ввести номер клетки заново.

```
String steps = "";
System.out.print("Крестики, введите номер клетки по горизонтали: ");
int b = scanner.nextInt();
String b1 = Integer.toString(b);
System.out.print("По вертикали: ");
int a = scanner.nextInt();
String a1 = Integer.toString(a);

/*while (true){
    if (steps.contains(a1+b1)){
        System.out.println("This cell is already occupied");
    }
    else break;
}*/

field[a][b] = 'x';
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
        System.out.print(field[i][j]+" | ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
steps = steps+a1+b1+" ";
```

Comment: ну вот у вас же есть уже `while(true)` (хоть и через одно место) - внесите логику ввода значения внутрь цикла

Comment: Незачем вносить во внутрь цикла. Просто проверку добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто добавить проверочное условие, и если клетка не занята - заполнять. Не нужно проверять в цикле, contains найдет вхождения в строку, которая в вашем случае является логом.

```
if (steps.contains(a1+b1)){
    System.out.println("This cell is already occupied");
}
else {
    steps = steps+a1+b1+" ";
    field[a][b] = 'x';
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
            System.out.print(field[i][j]+" | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Вся игра должна проходить в цикле

```
boolean gameNotEnds = false;
while (gameNotEnds) {

    ...
    System.out.print("Введите номер клетки по горизонтали: ");
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    String b1 = Integer.toString(b);
    System.out.print("По вертикали: ");
    int a = scanner.nextInt();

    ...
}
```